# progress/percent bar when page is loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

I have a case in which I created. 
work the system is processing data to be saved to the database. and it turns out it was a long process because of large data. 
so when in page proses.php seen still running. 
I want to add a progress bar in a page proses.php. thus seen in the percentage of the entry of data into the database. I am confused with the code that will I make? I know it uses jquery or javascript, but I dont know how encodes.

to do it, I use the 2 main files :
- form.html for data input, and
- process.php to run process data into the database

form.html code as follows:

```
<form name="form1" action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>File:
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Run"/>
</form>
```

process.php code approximately as follows:

```
<?php
    ......
    ......
    //the process data
    $sql = "insert into table1 .......;
    mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: If you did this with AJAX there is certainly a way. I'm not 100% of the method which is why I'm not submitting this an as answer but hopefully this http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/ will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: where I put it? proses.php? or form.html? and code "url" content of what I?

Comment: It's Javascript so it certainly wouldn't go in .PHP. You'll need to create an external .JS webpage, reference jQuery before it, and add this code into your .JS webpage. If you don't understand basic JS/jQuery I wouldn't attempt it, but rather read more on the subject first.

Comment: A progress bar with a single php script won't work.  When loading PHP in the browser, nothing is sent until the script is fully loaded, thus you can't determine what it is doing / what step it is on at a certain time.

Comment: no, in process.php not just a single php, html so there is also in it, including javascript. what still could not make progess bar?